# Android Video editor

Tags: android

I have to do flowing Task.

Record/capture video via android camera which I am able to do using andorid "MediaRecoder". However want to put markers into video inform of image/text. The image and text will be set of 2 03 images. We would like to overlay markers (image) in to the original video.

Please some library which is easy to use and would o this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But it will not be so easy,
You need to learn about these api's

1. [MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) to extract data/track from file.
2. [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) if you want to encode/decode
3. [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) to mux it into mp4 file

You can use all three of them together if you need to or individually.
You can find some example code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android-5.1.1_r1/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.